# How to take input from console without stopping program

Tags: python-3.x

I have been programing a Python discord bot (you don't need to know anything about discord for this question). I currently have it able to take in messages from discord, and want to be able to send messages by typing them into the console. Unfortunately, using input() completely stops the program, which is kind of a deal breaker. Is there a way to take input from the console without stopping the whole program?

Comment: Checkout [threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm). For future reference SO isnt really the right forum for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

In asynchronous mode you can create a worker that reads the standard input and pushes the result into a fifo queue and a main program that reads the output from the fifo when it has time.
The python documentation shows an example that uses this principle (but of course the actions of the worker and the main program are not the ones you want): https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#examples